# Error response when sending data to prisma

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I am working on a crud app using prisma and postgres. Currently I am getting error response when submitting data via POST method. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

api:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { prisma } from "../../lib/prisma";

const {title, content} = req.body
try {
    await prisma.note.create({
        data: {
                title,
                content
        }
    })
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Note Created'})
} catch (error) {
 res.status(500).json({error: "Something went wrong"})
```

Fetch function:

```
 async function create(data: FormData) {
   try{
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/create', {
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
 }).then(() =>{setForm({title: '',content: '',id: '',
    })
 })
  }catch(err){
console.log(err)
```

}
}

Handle Submit:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (data: FormData) => {
try {
 create(data) 
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `create` function, you are calling `JSON.stringify` on an instance of `FormData`. This will result in an empty object, even if the `FormData` contains the correct values.

`Object.fromEntries(data.entries())` will give you a plain object of the `FormData` entries, then you can call `JSON.stringify` on the result of that operation.